# How can I set up OpenDNS on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: command-line, dns

OpenDNS recommends a set of terminal commands in order to set it up on an Ubuntu computer. The problem is that the commands `gksudo` and `supersede` don't work on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

[Here on OpenDNS support](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228007087-Ubuntu) it says

> To avoid having your settings get revoked after reboots, or after periods of inactivity, you may need to make the following changes via the command line:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.auto
> ```
>
> NOTE: The dhclient.conf location may vary depending on your Linux distribution.
>
> To locate the correct file you can use:
>
> ```
> sudo find /etc -name dhclient.conf
> gksudo gedit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
> ```
>
> Add the following line to the document before the 'require subnet-mask' command
>
> ```
> supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220;
> ```
>
> Save and exit
>
> ```
> sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0                     "
> ```

Comment: Maybe just use dnsmasq and configure it to query opendns.

Comment: Steps 1-7 in the OpenDNS instructions are all you need to do... except in newer versions of Ubuntu, after you manually add the DNS servers, make sure to click DNS AUTO to OFF.

Comment: heynnema, thanks so much for your advice. It worked! I did not try Michael Przybylowicz's advice. Thanks very much.